# Breach of precept term

Tags: terminology, precept

What is the Pali or Sanskrit term for a breach of a precept?
I have checked http://dictionary.tamilcube.com/pali-dictionary.aspx and found 
breach of morality defined as sīlabheda . Is there a broader or more inclusive term?

Answer (score 3):

*sīlabheda* is not a common used term, I don't think. More common is *sīlavipatti* - transgression of morality. Another is *vītikkama* - transgression.

> tattha katamā sīlavipatti? yo kāyiko vītikkamo, vācasiko vītikkamo , kāyikavācasiko vītikkamo -- ayaṃ vuccati sīlavipatti. sabbampi dussilyaṃ sīlavipatti.
>   (dhammasaṅgaṇī, nikkhepakaṇḍaṃ, suttantikadukanikkhepaṃ)

The common Pali term for an offence against the rules of the vinaya is *āpatti*. Another common, related word is *dussīla*, a person with bad moral character.